# How to drop the las element in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, parsing, python-2.7

I have the following list:

```
l = [["string string...string, 'tag'"],["string....string, 'tag'"],...,["string...string, 'tag'"]]
```

How can i delete `'tag'` from the above list `l`?. I tried the following:

```
splited = [l.pop() for x in l]
```

But I delete only the last sublist. Any idea of how to aproach this?.

I would like to obtain the following:

```
splitted = l = [["string string...string"],["string....string"],...,["string...string"]]
```

Is this possible?.

Comment: Are you trying to pop the last element in EACH list, or the last element in the LAST list?

Comment: sorry guys I edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use slice:

```
splitted = [x[:-1] for x in l]
```

If you have large list and memory consumption is important, just iterate your list and remove last elements from sub lists:

```
for x in l:
    del x[-1]
```

**update (if sublists is lists with one string element really?):**

You can use string `split` function to split by comma:

```
l = [["string string...string, 'tag'"],
     ["string....string, 'tag'"],
     ["string...string, 'tag'"]]
splitted = [[x[0].split(',')[0]] for x in l]
```

Demo:

```
>>> l = [["string string...string, 'tag'"],["string....string, 'tag'"],["string...string, 'tag'"]]
>>> [[x[0].split(',')[0]] for x in l]
[['string string...string'], ['string....string'], ['string...string']]
```

Comment: @newWithPython can you post list contents that you have initially?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are `pop`ing from `corpus`, as many times as there are sublists in `L` in `[corpus.pop() for x in L]`, which essentially translates to:

```
for x in L:
    corpus.pop()
```

Clearly, this doesn't modify `L` at all. Try one of these instead:

```
In [7]: L
Out[7]: 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 'a'],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 'a'],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 'a'],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 'a'],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 'a']]

In [8]: L = [s[:-1] for s in L]

In [9]: L
Out[9]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Or:

```
In [12]: L
Out[12]: 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 'a'],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 'a'],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 'a'],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 'a'],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 'a']]

In [13]: [s.pop() for s in L]
Out[13]: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']

In [14]: L
Out[14]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```